# How to remove duplicate entries from a mysql db?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table with some ids + titles. I want to make the title column unique, but it has over 600k records already, some of which are duplicates (sometimes several dozen times over).

How do I remove all duplicates, except one, so I can add a UNIQUE key to the title column after?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This command adds a unique key, and drops all rows that generate errors (due to the unique key). This removes duplicates.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1(title);
```

---

Edit: Note that this command [may not work for InnoDB tables](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40344) for some versions of MySQL. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053812/190597) for a workaround. (Thanks to "an anonymous user" for this information.)

Comment: its not working on MySQL client version: 5.5.28, what should we do for this version?

Comment: Sorry old I know, but is there a way to do this without resetting the Primary Key Index / Auto_Increment number? Just to delete them and not truncate the number back too? Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me *only after changing engine to MyISAM*. Try `ALTER TABLE table ENGINE = MyISAM`.

Comment: Worked for me after using `set session old_alter_table=1;` first.

Comment: It does not work for the last versions of MySQL:   _As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error._  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-index

Comment: Further information about deprecating and removing `ALTER IGNORE TABLE`: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395

Answer (score 12):

Create a new table with just the distinct rows of the original table. There may be other ways but I find this the cleanest.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table AS SELECT DISTINCT [....] FROM main_table
```

[More specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40757125/453673):
The faster way is to insert distinct rows into a temporary table. Using delete, it took me a few hours to remove duplicates from a table of 8 million rows. Using insert and distinct, it took just 13 minutes.

```
CREATE TABLE tempTableName LIKE tableName;  
CREATE INDEX ix_all_id ON tableName(cellId,attributeId,entityRowId,value);  
INSERT INTO tempTableName(cellId,attributeId,entityRowId,value) SELECT DISTINCT cellId,attributeId,entityRowId,value FROM tableName;  
DROP TABLE tableName;  
INSERT tableName SELECT * FROM tempTableName;  
DROP TABLE tempTableName;
```

Comment: other answers may have worked in previous versions but don't work now. but this one works well and is fast. i found it useful.

Comment: Hi, nice answer but something scratches my head. after the first drop table tableName shouldn't we do CREATE TABLE tableName LIKE tempTableName; ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the MySql `ALTER IGNORE TABLE` [has been deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395), you need to actually delete the duplicate date before adding an index.

First write a query that finds all the duplicates.   Here I'm assuming that `email` is the field that contains duplicates.

```
SELECT
    s1.email
    s1.id, 
    s1.created
    s2.id,
    s2.created 
FROM 
    student AS s1 
INNER JOIN 
    student AS s2 
WHERE 
    /* Emails are the same */
    s1.email = s2.email AND
    /* DON'T select both accounts,
       only select the one created later.
       The serial id could also be used here */
    s2.created > s1.created 
;
```

Next select only the unique duplicate ids:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT s2.id
FROM 
    student AS s1 
INNER JOIN 
    student AS s2 
WHERE 
    s1.email = s2.email AND
    s2.created > s1.created 
;
```

Once you are sure that only contains the duplicate ids you want to delete, run the delete.  You have to add `(SELECT * FROM tblname)` so that MySql doesn't complain.

```
DELETE FROM
    student 
WHERE
    id
IN (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT s2.id
    FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM student) AS s1 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM student) AS s2 
    WHERE 
        s1.email = s2.email AND
        s2.created > s1.created 
);
```

Then create the unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE
    student
ADD UNIQUE INDEX
    idx_student_unique_email(email)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query can be used to delete all the duplicate except the one row with lowest "id" field value

```
DELETE t1 FROM table_name t1, table_name t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name
```

In the similar way, we can keep the row with the highest value in 'id' as follows

```
 DELETE t1 FROM table_name t1, table_name t2 WHERE t1.id < t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to do it in SQL2000.  I'm not completely familiar with MySQL syntax but I'm sure there's something comparable

```
create table #titles (iid int identity (1, 1), title varchar(200))

-- Repeat this step many times to create duplicates
insert into #titles(title) values ('bob')
insert into #titles(title) values ('bob1')
insert into #titles(title) values ('bob2')
insert into #titles(title) values ('bob3')
insert into #titles(title) values ('bob4')


DELETE T  FROM 
#titles T left join 
(
  select title, min(iid) as minid from #titles group by title
) D on T.title = D.title and T.iid = D.minid
WHERE D.minid is null

Select * FROM #titles
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from student where id in (
SELECT distinct(s1.`student_id`) from student as s1 inner join student as s2
where s1.`sex` = s2.`sex` and
s1.`student_id` > s2.`student_id` and
s1.`sex` = 'M'
    ORDER BY `s1`.`student_id` ASC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by Nitin seems to be the most elegant / logical one.

However it has one issue:

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'student' for
>   update in FROM clause

This can however be resolved by using (SELECT * FROM student) instead of student:

```
DELETE FROM student WHERE id IN (
SELECT distinct(s1.`student_id`) FROM (SELECT * FROM student) AS s1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM student) AS s2
WHERE s1.`sex` = s2.`sex` AND
s1.`student_id` > s2.`student_id` AND
s1.`sex` = 'M'
ORDER BY `s1`.`student_id` ASC
)
```

Give your +1's to Nitin for coming up with the original solution.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting duplicates on MySQL tables is a common issue, that usually comes with specific needs. In case anyone is interested, here ([Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql/47392593#47392593)) I explain how to use a temporary table to delete MySQL duplicates in a reliable and fast way (with examples for different use cases).

In this case, something like this should work:

```
-- create a new temporary table
CREATE TABLE tmp_table1 LIKE table1;

-- add a unique constraint    
ALTER TABLE tmp_table1 ADD UNIQUE(id, title);

-- scan over the table to insert entries
INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp_table1 SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY sid;

-- rename tables
RENAME TABLE table1 TO backup_table1, tmp_table1 TO table1;
```