# Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

How would I delete all duplicate data from a MySQL Table?

For example, with the following data:

```
SELECT * FROM names;

+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | google |
| 2  | yahoo  |
| 3  | msn    |
| 4  | google |
| 5  | google |
| 6  | yahoo  |
+----+--------+
```

I would use `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM names;` if it were a `SELECT` query.

How would I do this with `DELETE` to only remove duplicates and keep just one record of each?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867530/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-mysql-db  (Ironically.)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate question, as this asks specifically for a DELETE command to perform the same action that an ALTER command adding a unique index would be needed to have MySQL automatically remove duplicate rows. In this case, we're choosing how exactly we want to delete the duplicates.

Comment: So a question about duplicates has duplicates? Hmm

Answer (score 1035, accepted):

> **Editor warning: This solution is computationally inefficient and may bring down your connection for a large table.**

**NB - You *need* to do this first on a *test copy* of your table!**

**When I did it, I found that unless I also included `AND n1.id <> n2.id`, it deleted every row in the table.**

1. If you want to keep the row with the lowest `id` value:

   ```sql
   DELETE n1 FROM names n1, names n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name
   ```
2. If you want to keep the row with the highest `id` value:

   ```sql
   DELETE n1 FROM names n1, names n2 WHERE n1.id < n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name
   ```

I used this method in MySQL 5.1

Not sure about other versions.

---

**Update: Since people Googling for removing duplicates end up here**
Although the OP's question is about `DELETE`, please be advised that using `INSERT` and `DISTINCT` is much faster. For a database with 8 million rows, the below query took 13 minutes, while using `DELETE`, it took more than 2 hours and yet didn't complete.

```
INSERT INTO tempTableName(cellId,attributeId,entityRowId,value)
    SELECT DISTINCT cellId,attributeId,entityRowId,value
    FROM tableName;
```

Comment: Excellent solution. It worked perfectly. But I have one suggestion here we should swap the conditions. Instead of [WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name] we should write [WHERE n1.name = n2.name AND n1.id > n2.id] it will improve performance if we have so much data.

Comment: FYI:  This ignores rows where column "name" is null.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5df9 for a schema example. May need to load in your instance of MySQL.  Then execute:  SELECT * FROM deldup;  DELETE n1 FROM deldup n1, deldup n2 WHERE n1.or_id < n2.or_id AND n1.order_id = n2.order_id AND n1.txt_value = n2.txt_value AND n1.date_of_revision = n2.date_of_revision AND n1.status = n2.status;  SELECT * FROM deldup;

Comment: @user307635 I think that the mysql optimizer will handle the correct order?

Comment: When I try to replace `DELETE` with `SELECT` i get a `unknown column n1 in field list` ? Does this only work with `DELETE`? (mysql 5.5)

Comment: @Peterdk DELETE takes a table name (required if you specify more than one table), SELECT takes column name(s),  or try "SELECT * ...".

Comment: The NB in this answer is VERY IMPORTANT kids. But this is an excellent of MySQL. NOTE that for tables that could have duplicates repeated more than once you will also want a `GROUP BY` n1.id clause.

Comment: I love this solution, but do you have a suggestion for optimizing it on larger tables?

Comment: So how does this work with large tables? I have 400k+ rows. It works on the sqlfiddle given above though.

Comment: Be careful! MySQL's `=` sign is not case sensitive. This will delete `Test Name` as it will match `test name`.

Comment: what does n1 represents? is it the column?

Comment: @mmr n1 is the table alias (...FROM names n1)

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly when `ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE INDEX index1(table.column_name)` doesn't work

Comment: somehow it didnt work, for me it deleted all values which had duplicates. The below query worked fine.

Comment: Dude, with a "n.b." like that you should put that BEFORE everything else!

Comment: What could happen if `n1.id` and `n2.id` might also be duplicated?

Comment: This took 171 seconds on a 10,000 record table with 450 duplicates. The answer by  OMG Ponies took 4 seconds.

Comment: No doubt, its the most elegant and excellent solution...saved my time :)

Comment: and I am running it every few days...thinking to write a small script to do it via cron..thanks a million for this straightforward solution..would that I could more than one upvote option

Comment: This query doesn't work on MySQL version: 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: on mysql 5.7 (centos) and this doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: The DISTINCT solution is great, but be careful.  If you only had two columns, an ID and a name, you could condense the rows by names - but what if you had other fields with divergent values (which you could tolerate losing one or more duplicates of)?  In this case `DISTINCT` won't work because of the extra field.  In this case use `INSERT INTO tmp SELECT .. GROUP BY..`.  _ALSO_, be careful on your rename sequence and your innoDB foreign key references!!  And make sure you don't lose any indexes.  All good things to check.

Comment: OH, and on my method above, use MIN(id) if you want to select the first, MAX(id) if you want to select that last.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql/47392593#47392593) I explain how to use a temporary table to delete MySQL duplicates in a reliable and fast way (with examples for different use cases).

Comment: Great! But, is there any faster solution? for example for a table with 2 Millions Records.

Comment: This should not be selected answer. I have very short datas on my table with 100,000 rows, and your query made my server down with mysql too many connections error. I waited 10 minutes to see the results but it didnt. I ended up with stopping the query and restarting my mysql server to get my server back.

Comment: @user198989 - agreed; OMG Ponies answer is inherently faster on large tables. Especially true if there are multiple duplicates of each record.

Comment: This will not work if there are more than 2 duplicate rows. please check again.

Comment: @martin.masa May I know how about the update statement?Something like soft delete, set a date in columns deleted_at

Comment: The INSERT INTO with SELECT DISTINCT method worked perfectly, and has been said here, quickly. For whatever reason this was the only method I tried in a long annoying day that did what was promised.

Answer (score 247):

If you want to keep the row with the lowest `id` value:

```
DELETE FROM NAMES
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MIN(n.id)
                            FROM NAMES n
                        GROUP BY n.name) x)
```

If you want the `id` value that is the highest:

```
DELETE FROM NAMES
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.id)
                            FROM NAMES n
                        GROUP BY n.name) x)
```

The subquery in a subquery is necessary for MySQL, or you'll get a 1093 error.

Comment: What does the 'x' do ?

Comment: @GDmac it serves as an alias for inner query. If not specified, an error will be thrown.

Comment: This is a much better solution. The one by masa-255 doesn't work. What is the x for?

Comment: @wbinky it serves as an alias for inner query. If not specified, an error will be thrown.

Comment: But what's the x for?  (just kidding)

Comment: it seems this sql delete unique rows too. actualy all rows

Comment: what if i have same id

Comment: This is a better solution than masa-255's one if you have big data. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it just like use temporary table

Comment: @GDmac : Alias is required for every derived table. x is here serving as an alias for the table derived from the custom query.

Comment: @Asmita you can use `DELETE FROM NAMES
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.id)
                            FROM NAMES n
                        GROUP BY n.id) x)`

Comment: It is executed very long

Comment: `x` could be written as `AS x` or `AS temp` or `AS \`temp\`` to make it more clear it's a random alias name for the table generated by the outer select. MySQL won't let you use the same table for both an action (DELETE, UPDATE) and a condition, so wrapping the condition in another SELECT allows a temp table to be created and given an alias.

Comment: This took only 8 seconds to a table with 500K records. Thanks.

Comment: This was super fast compared to the accepted answer!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is much much much faster

Comment: Superfast, but this has also deleted unique rows too. It cost me 20K+ unique data deleted with this query.

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan - To avoid deleting rows unintentionally, the query *must* return a row for *every* existing value of the `group by` field(s). That is, this approach *must not* be used with a more complicated inner query. For example, if one alters the query to only select rows from a given id range or date range (or other limited part of the table), then the `DELETE` will delete all data not in the specified range. In more complicated situations, it is best to make a temporary table containing IDs to be deleted. Then if a row shouldn't be in that temp table, a 2nd query can correct it.

Comment: This solution gives me the error 'SQL Error [1093] [HY000]: You can't specify target table 'NAMES' for update in FROM clause'

Comment: Why did you use two selects? I removed the outer one (SELECT * FROM) and it worked just fine.