# MSSQL Query to delete duplicate rows from a TABLE leaving distinct rows in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to **delete all duplicate rows except the first occurrence** of similar rows from a Table `Log` having the same `customer_id` and `deactivation_date`. How do I achieve that with minimum number of sql statements.

I Am using MS SQL Server 2008 express edition.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: @Arion sql 2008 express edition

Comment: Does this "log" table have an id of it's own, that's unique to each row?

Comment: Hey Akhil, you want to keep only one unique record? or the first One record?

Comment: @Bridge Log table has unique id log_id

Comment: see this :-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque I need to keep the first record

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM Log WHERE LogId NOT IN 
 (SELECT Min(LogId) FROM Log GROUP BY customer_id, deactivation_date)
```

Answer (score 14):

Or:

```
with cte as (
    select row_number() over (partition by customer_id, deactivation_date
    order by log_id) as rn
    from Log)
delete from cte
    where rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not giving us much to work on. But maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Log].customer_id ORDER BY 
                              deactivation_date) AS RowNbr,
        [Log].*
    FROM
        [Log]
)
DELETE FROM [Log]
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            CTE
        WHERE
            CTE.RowNbr>1
            AND CTE.log_id =[Log].log_id 
    )
```