# what is the best way to do "nodupkey" ( SAS ) in mySQL ?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sas

Can any one please let me know what would be the most efficient way the create "nodupkey" like in mySQL thay would give the same result as SAS code here ?

```
  Proc sort data=T1 nodupkey out = T2; By ID; Run;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you use something like "select distinct id,... from T1, order by ID"?

Comment: Davb you should make your comment an answer...that's it

Answer (score 1):

seems like a simple distinct could be enough for your case, so your MySQL code should look like this:

```
create table T2 
 select distinct ID
 from T1
```

More information can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)

Hope this help

**EDIT:**

As Mozan say this is supposed to work only if you have a single varible on your table, named ID

Comment: This is wrong unless ID is the only variable in your dataset (column in your table). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql for a proper answer.