# MySQL Delete Rows With Duplicate Content

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)
>   [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

This is how my table looks like

```
1 | 1 | Hello
1 | 2 | Hello
1 | 3 | Hello
1 | 4 | some text
1 | 5 | text
1 | 6 | text
```

How can I delete all duplicate rows and just leave the last one; for example:

```
1 | 3 | Hello
1 | 4 | some text
1 | 6 | text
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please look to the Related questions bar in the right.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT col3, col1, MAX(col2) maxCol
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY col3, col1
        ) b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND
                a.col2 = b.maxCol AND
                a.col3 = b.col3
WHERE   b.col1 IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3728/1)