# Remove duplicates from MySQL table where 2 fields are the same

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

So I have a table with fields `ID` (AI, primary key), `ticker`, `priceDate`, `price`.

I have a bunch or records that share the same `priceDate` and `ticker`. There should only be one record per `ticker` for any given `priceDate`.

How would I go about removing these duplicate records, given that `priceDate` and `ticker` are not unique fields?

Comment: A solution to this question has already been posted.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql/5016434#5016434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from your_table
where id not in 
(
  select * from 
  (
    select min(id)
    from your_table
    group by pricedate, ticker
  ) x
)
```

Comment: Many thanks, think it did the trick. Out of interest what does the `x` at the end do?

Comment: If you define a subquery you need to name it with an alias. I used `x` as alias name.

Comment: BTW you need that sub query because MySQL won't allow you to delete from the same table you are selecting from. But with another subquery you can trick MySQL.