# Delete duplicate data from table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to delete all duplicate data from table and i don't know know which data is duplicate  in my table which query i can run in Mysql please help me

```
delete from tablename(record) where coluumnname(employer)=ram >0
```

it working but it's delete all record from table not duplicate

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: Since you've already removed all your data - create your table again with unique key and this will not allow you to insert duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

in general..

```
delete from <table_name> where rowid not in 
                       ( select min(rowid) 
                         from table group by column1..,column2,...column3..);
```

in your case

```
delete from table where employer not in 
   (select min(employer) from table group by employer order by 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

delete from record where employer='ram' limit 1