# MySQL remove duplicate rows with two same columns

Tags: mysql

I've got table with following columns:

```
id,name,attribute_id,params_desc
```

The data in table looks like this:

```
0,'some',1,'something'
1,'some',2,'somethingelse'
2,'some',3,'somethingelses'
3,'some',1,'something'
```

What I need is to remove duplicates, which have the same `name` and `attribute_id`.

I was unable to find some working solution here, as `DISTINCT` or `UNIQUE INDEX` or `INSERT IGNORE` did not work for me.

Thx for your time.

Comment: what would the result be exactly from the example data?  how do you know what you would keep?  (what happens with the other columns?)

Comment: I just want to save one copy, only the id is different and i dont care about that, in this example, remove last row

Comment: try the answer posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312098/623952 or here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4685232/623952

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tableName
ADD CONSTRAINT SomeName UNIQUE (name ,attribute_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE 
FROM tbl 
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id from tbl 
GROUP BY name,attribute_id 
HAVING COUNT(*)>2
)
```

Comment: `count(*)>=2`... would that delete all records of things with more than one occurrence?  i think OP wants to save one copy.

Comment: Your answer is giving me 1093 error Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Comment: It WILL delete ALL your duplicates.

Comment: you still need to change the `count(*)>2` to `>=2` otherwise it will only work for things with 3 or more duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies since I'm not sure the syntax is the same in MySQL as in SQLServer - however a quick google suggests it might be, otherwise perhaps this will point you in the right direction:

```
DELETE a FROM 
(
    SELECT id
            ,name
            ,attribute_id
            ,params_desc
            ,row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, attribute_id ORDER BY id ASC)
    FROM Table
) a
WHERE row > 1
```

Comment: mysql doesn't do `partition by`