# Avoid/remove duplicate row in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table for friendship

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friendList` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_friend` int(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have some entries like :

Entry A : 1-2

Entry B : 2-1

Entry C : 1-2

Entry A & B show that the user 1 is friend with user 2. But the entry C is useless, so i need to delete it.

Is there way i can delete all duplicate row or apply specific constraint to avoid that?

Thanks !

Comment: what is your table structure>

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: The thing is that the id key is not unique and is not meant to be. I was looking for another solution than adding a unique primary key, but may be its just impossible. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a unique index for those 2 columns to enforce uniqueness:

```
alter table friendList add unique index(id, id_friend);
```

Comment: Hi i want also the entry 3-1 or 1-3 to be possible i just dont want two row with the same x-y couple (x=given int, y=given int)

Comment: That is ok as 3-1 is not the same as 1-3.

Comment: Yeah it worked, i think i just didn't understand well what unique index is then. Thanks a lot :)