# mysql - Remove all duplicate records except one record

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all duplicate records from my table except one record (tbl_user_points)

**Table Data**

```
id  userid  points  Reason
------------------------------
132 1278    50  Bonus points
153 1278    50  Bonus points
174 1278    50  Bonus points
195 1278    50  Bonus points
```

So my final output will be

```
id  userid  points  Reason
------------------------------
132 1278    50  Bonus points
```

Please help me on this

Comment: Are you using any scripting language like C#, PHP, VB.net, etc to accompany SQL?

Comment: I am using PHP & MYSQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   Delete
       t1
    FROM 
       tTable t1, tTable t2 
    WHERE 
       t1.userid  = t2.userid  AND 
       t1.points  = t2.points  AND 
       t1.Reason  = t2.Reason AND 
       t1.id < t2.id
```

**(Or)**

This will always leave the row with the lowest ID -

```
  DELETE t2
    FROM `table` t1
    INNER JOIN `table` t2
        ON t1.userid  = t2.userid  AND 
           t1.points  = t2.points  AND 
           t1.Reason  = t2.Reason AND 
           t1.id < t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_user_points
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM tbl_user_points GROUP BY userid, points, Reason
)
```

Comment: I was going to post something that involves PHP manipulation before it passes the SQL statement against the database, but then you answered with this post, pure SQL. I didn't try this but it makes a lot of sense judging by the syntax. Thank you Sir, I learned something from this.

Comment: MySql don't allow to Same table_name in target and sub-query. got this error after executing the query
`Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tbl_user_points' for update in FROM clause.`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
DELETE FROM tbl_user_points
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT * FROM(SELECT id FROM tbl_user_points1 GROUP BY userid, points, reason
    ) AS p)
```