# How to remove duplicate items in MySQL with a dataset of 20 million rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got big MySQL database. I need to delete the duplicate item quickly. Here's how it looks:

```
id | text1 | text2|    
1  | 23    |  43  |   
2  | 23    |  44  |  
3  | 23    |  44  |
```

After the deleting, the remain part of table should be:

```
id | text1 | text2|   
1  | 23    |  43  |   
3  | 23    |  44  |
```

I don't care about the id. the most important is no duplicate items will be disappear.

Comment: "Not caring" is sometimes indicative of larger problems! You *should* care!

Comment: Id doesn't mean any thing in my project. It can be any number. The only thing I want is to remove all of duplicate items

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: I think Strawberry means that you should care about this at the beginning of your project to avoid all duplicated items!

Comment: Couldn't you just prevent duplicates so you'd not need to remove them? Define unique index across (text1, text2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE my_tablename ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (text1 , text2);
```

ie, try to add `UNIQUE INDEX` to your columns and `alter` the table

This has an **advantage** that in future also there will be no duplicate rows which you can insert in your table

Comment: I've never tried this - out of interest, does the `IGNORE` clause mean that dup rows are silently ignored? +1

Comment: @halfer:- Yes for sure!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT MIN(id) FROM t GROUP BY text1, text2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), text1, text2
GROUP BY text1, text2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

When you find rows here, delete one row for each match, and then run it again.

I'm not sure what it will be like in terms of performance - perhaps it doesn't matter, if you do this offline?

Comment: group by is not efficient. it will takes a long time.

Comment: Are you sure that matters, in this case? In many cases of "it needs to be fast", it doesn't need to be. Can you do the query offline?