# how to delete duplicate items in an efficient way

Tags: python, mysql, algorithm

The dataset structure like this:

```
   | text1 | text2|    
   | 23    |  43  |   
   | 44    |  23  |  
   | 23    |  44  |
```

After the deleting, the remain part should be:

```
   | text1 | text2|   
   | 23    |  43  |   
   | 23    |  44  |
```

If a.Text1 == b.text2 and a.text2 == b.text1, then delete one of both.

As I have around one million items, is there any efficient way to do this? I can use the Python and MySQL database if needed.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: For tables without unique ID the only universal solution is to copy unique rows to a temporary table, truncate the original and insert from the temp.

Comment: @dkurbz Thanks guys. I have some methods, however, it would take around 10 hours. I am here to ask if there has any more efficient method.

Comment: For tables with unique IDs you already got answers in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811865/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-in-mysql-with-a-dataset-of-20-million-rows?rq=1).

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks. It would take a long time.

Comment: @PM77-1 These are two different questions.

Comment: Well... Unless you plan to run MySQL on your old laptop it wouldn't take that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to do this type of deletion is often to do `truncate` and `insert`.  Something like:

```
create temporary table t as
    select least(text1, text2) as text1, greatest(text1, text2) as text2
    from dataset t
    group by least(text1, text2), greatest(text1, text2);

truncate table dataset;

insert into dataset(text1, text2)
    select text1, text2
    from t;
```

Comment: +1 and for an efficient way, instead of using a table for words, use `Trie<Character>`, where Nodes have a count