# How to make delete duplicates faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

On a table with about 1.7M rows, I tried to delete duplicates posts:

```
delete a FROM comment a
  INNER JOIN comment a2
     WHERE a.id < a2.id
     AND   a.body = a2.body;
```

The result was:

```
  Query OK, 35071 rows affected (5 hours 36 min 48.79 sec)
```

This happened on my almost idle workstation with `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz`. 
I'm wondering if there are some tricks to make this delete operation faster?

Comment: Its not good idea to delete them all in one go, try incremental delete with a filter clause ex: using a date column in `filer`

Comment: how many rows  you have in your table comment ??  .. you leave on db only the last comment for duplicate by name?

Comment: @Ven, please elaborate with a sample query.

Comment: @scaisEdge, as I said, there are roughly 1.7 million rows.

Comment: @Milkyway if you have a column a table that can be used for deleting records, i have solved this issue in production this way. As this will not cause issues on log file growth ex:  `delete a from comment a inner join comment a2 on a.body = a2.body and a.datecolumn between '2018-01-06' and '2019-01-06'`

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL specifically you can try (assuming rows have the exact same columns information):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE comment ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (id, body);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811865/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-in-mysql-with-a-dataset-of-20-million-rows)

Comment: Not sure how to implement that in my particular use case.

Comment: This does not work for mysql. I get `#1327 - Undeclared variable: NewTable`, despite the fact that I've created it:  `CREATE TABLE `NewTable` LIKE `comment`;` Also the rename command at mysql should be `RENAME TABLE `NewTable` TO `comment`;`

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question's requirement.

Comment: Whats Performance hit adding index on table with 1.7 million rows, and how long does it take to execute ?

Answer (score 0):

The below query will be useful for you.

```
Delete  YourTableName 
From    (
Select  row_number() over(Partition by ColName1,ColName2,ColName3 order by ColName1,ColName2,ColName3 Asc)As RowNumber
        )YourTableName
Where   YourTableName.RowNumber>1
```

if it's working kindly mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

Your query is attempting a zillion deletes for the same row.  For instance, if you have this data:

```
body   id
  a     1
  a     2
  a     3
  a     4
```

Then your query attempts the following deletions:

```
 c.body   c.id  c2.id
  a         1      4
  a         1      3
  a         1      2
  a         2      4
  a         2      3
  a         3      4
```

You can see how this would result in lots of work for the database, as the number of `id`s on a given `body` increase.

You can fix this using `group by` instead:

```
delete c 
    from comment c join
         (select c2.body, max(c2.id) as max_id
          from comment c2
          group by c2.body
         ) c2
         on c2.body = c.body and c.id < c2.max_id;
```

In addition, you want an index on `comment(body, id)`.

You might also find that an anti-join works better than the join you are attempting:

```
delete c 
    from comment c left join
         comment c2
         on c2.body = c.body and c2.id > c.id
    where c2.id is null;
```

Comment: This wasn't any better. I tried it on a table with 370K rows on the same machine and here is the result: `Query OK, 27875 rows affected (10 hours 57 min 26.10 sec)`

Comment: @Milkyway . . . Did you create the index that the answer recommends?

Comment: no I didn't. I'll try that on another table and give feedback. Thanks.