# Delete duplicate column value from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I have mysql table named `emails` where multiple column like

```
"first_name","last_name","email","contact"
```

I have huge data in this table with many multiple email id. 
I want to make this data as unique where not any single email in other row.

Kindly share how to write SQL query for it

Thanks
Paras

Comment: Are you able to delete duplicates from this data?

Comment: You can use one table with different aliases look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: Also do the multiple email ID's have different first/last names or contact values?

Answer (score 1):

First you may need to find the list of duplicate emails using the following query.

```
select email, COUNT(*) as cnt  
FROM emails   
group by email  
order by cnt desc
```

The query will give emails and the count of repetition. Then based on which record is valid, take deletion steps.

Comment: Thanks for helping

I want to delete duplicate entry from emails table where email column has duplicate value.

Comment: yes i get list of duplicate entry. using SELECT query you given

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM emails
WHERE email IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT email 
    FROM emails
    WHERE email IN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Number],
               email,
               first_name,
               last_name,
               contact
        FROM emails   
        GROUP BY email, first_name, last_name, contact
                   )
               )
```

Then if it returns the correct results use this

```
DELETE FROM emails
WHERE email IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM emails
    WHERE email IN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Number],
               email,
               first_name,
               last_name,
               contact
        FROM emails   
        GROUP BY email, first_name, last_name, contact
                   )
               )
```

Comment: I have done select query and get error as bellow
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM emails WHERE email IN ( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM emails WHERE em' at line 1

Comment: @ParasParmar Needs to be SELECT * FROM, update my answer

Comment: SELECT * FROM emails
WHERE email IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM emails
    WHERE email IN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Number]
               email,
               first_name,
               last_name,
               contact
        FROM emails   
        GROUP BY email, first_name, last_name, contact
                   )
               )


this is gives error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[1] email FROM emails GROUP BY email ' at line 6

Comment: @ParasParmar Have a go now