# Delete duplicate columns in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say I have three columns in my SQL database like that

```
ID | NAME | PHONE
-----------------    
 1 | JEFF | 467
 2 | JEFF | 489
 3 | JOHN | 234
 4 | JACK | 323
 5 | JEFF | 378
```

I want to write a SQL query that deletes all the rows where every double `NAME` occurence is detected. This means after running the SQL query, the table should look like this:

```
ID | NAME | PHONE
-----------------
 1 | JEFF | 467
 2 | JOHN | 234
 3 | JACK | 323
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Thank you very much, i changed it to this now

```
delete from product_list y
    where exists (select 1 from product_list y2 where y.model = y2.model and y2.linkid < y.linkid);
```

but i always get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete * from product_list y where exists (select 1 from product_list y2 whe' at line 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean, delete rows where a duplicate exists?

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Ans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @user3877230 Is 'ID' meant to be used for a single column PK?

Answer (score 11):

The standard SQL approach to this is:

```
delete from yourtable y
    where exists (select 1 from yourtable y2 where y.name = y2.name and y2.id < y.id);
```

That is, delete all records where there exists a record with the same name and a lower id.

If you only want to return the rows, use the same idea:

```
select y.*
from yourtable y
where not exists (select 1 from yourtable y2 where y.name = y2.name and y2.id < y.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should work. In this query Employee is my table name and Employee-id is key.

```
DELETE from Employee WHERE EmpID in(select EmpID from Employee GROUP BY EmpId HAVING COUNT(*) >1)
```