# how to delete repeated rows while retrieving data's

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

i have a song name in db, while updating, there are more duplicated rows in db

for example :-

```
ID - 200  | TAGS - akon
ID - 201  | TAGS - akon
ID - 204  | TAGS - akon
```

i need to omit duplicate data's or delete those duplicate rows.

i am retrieving data usings

```
<? 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags  WHERE tag !='' ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 30");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $title = str_replace('-',' ',$row['tag']);
  if (strlen($title) > 50)
    $title = substr($title, 0, strrpos(substr($title, 0, 50), ' ')) . '...';
  $title = str_replace('---','-',$title);
  $title = str_replace('--','-',$title);
  $tag = str_replace('---','-',$row['tag']);
  $tag = str_replace('--','-',$tag);
  echo "<a href=/mp3/".UrlText($tag)."/ title=\"".$title." \">".$title . " </a> :: "; 
}
?>
```

i need to omit or delete those duplicated rows and show only unique content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` to select  non duplicated tags:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT tag
FROM tags  
WHERE tag !='' 
ORDER by id DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: how to delete those duplicate rows from db

Comment: +1 Distinct doesn't require or use parenthesis.  Luckily, `(col1)` is the same as `col1`.  And the SQL standard not equal operator is `<>`, not `!=`, though both work in MySQL.

Comment: @user3663603: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Comment: @Andomar thanks, parenthesis it's a habit I have that sometime I forget in mysql. If you want to delete duplicated rows there's plenty of posts, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql).