# Deleting duplicate data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to emulate the accepted answer in this SO question:  [**Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL? [duplicate]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql) with a twist, I want the data (auto-incrementing ID's) of one table to determine which rows to delete in another table.  [**SQLFiddle here showing data.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d00e/7)

In the fiddle referenced above, the end result I'm looking for is the rows in *`eventdetails_new`* with Event_ID = 4 & 6 to be deleted (EVENTDETAILS_ID's 5 & 6, and  9 & 10), leaving rows 3 & 5 (EVENTDETAILS_ID's 3 & 4 and 7 & 8).  I hope that made sense.  *Ideally* the rows in *`events_new`* with those same Event_ID's would get deleted as well (which I haven't started working on yet, so no code samples).

This is the query I'm trying to make work, but I'm a bit over my head:

```
SELECT *
FROM eventdetails_new AS EDN1, eventdetails_new AS EDN2
INNER JOIN events_new AS E1 ON `E1`.`Event_ID` = `EDN1`.`Event_ID`
INNER JOIN events_new AS E2 ON `E2`.`Event_ID` = `EDN2`.`Event_ID`
WHERE `E1`.`Event_ID` > `E2`.`Event_ID` 
AND `E1`.`DateTime` = `E2`.`DateTime`
AND events_new.EventType_ID = 6;
```

Here's the same [**SQLFiddle with the results of this query**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d00e/5).  Not good.  I can see the Event_ID in the data, but the query cannot for some reason.  Not sure how to proceed to fix this.

I know it's a SELECT query, but I couldn't figure out a way to have two aliased tables in the DELETE query (*which I think I need?*).  I figured if I could get a selection, I could delete it with some C# code.  However ideally it could all be done in a single query or set of statements without having to go outside of MySQL.

Here's my first cut at the query, but it's just as bad:

```
DELETE e1 FROM eventdetails_new e1 
WHERE `events_new`.`Event_ID` > `events_new`.`Event_ID` 
AND events_new.DateTime = events_new.DateTime AND events_new.EventType_ID = 6;
```

SQLFiddle won't let me run this query at all, so it's not much help.  However, it give me the same error as the one above:  `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'events_new.Event_ID' in 'where clause'`

**I'm by no means married to either of these queries if there's a better way.  The end result I'm looking for is deleting a bunch of duplicate data.**

I have hundreds of thousands of these results, and I know that roughly 1/3 of them are duplicates that I need to get rid of before we go live with the database.

Comment: How about a different approach: determine `SELECT` query to get the end result you are looking for using `DISTINCT` and/or `GROUP BY` to filter out duplicates. Then load the results into a temporary table. `TRUNCATE` your existing table (backup first!), then load with the results from the `SELECT`. I find it easier to get my head around selecting unique rows, then deleting duplicates. Not sure if this is an option so haven't posted as answer.

Comment: I'm open to any method to get this done.  Worst comes to worst, I can recreate the entire database from logs in about 5 hours and we're still in the "testing" phase (my company doesn't exactly understand the concept, although I'm digging my heels in on this).  If you can provide a code example that'd be outstanding.  The SQLFiddle I provided is a good example of what I'm looking at on an extremely small scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I eventually ended up doing.  My co-worker & I came up with a query that would give us a list of Event_ID's that had duplicate data (we actually used Access 2010's query builder and MySQL-ified it).  Bear in mind this is a complete solution where the original question didn't have as much detail as far as linked tables.  If you've got questions about this, feel free to ask & I'll try to help:

```
SELECT `Events_new`.`Event_ID`
    FROM Events_new
    GROUP BY `Events_new`.`PCBID`, `Events_new`.`EventType_ID`, `Events_new`.`DateTime`, `Events_new`.`User`
    HAVING (((COUNT(`Events_new`.`PCBID`)) > 1) AND ((COUNT(`Events_new`.`User`)) > 1) AND ((COUNT(`Events_new`.`DateTime`)) > 1))
```

From this I processed each `Event_ID` to remove the duplicates in an iterative manner.  Basically I had to delete all the child rows starting from the last lowest table so that I didn't run afoul of foreign key restraints.

This chunk of code was written in LinqPAD as C# statements: *(sbCommonFunctions is an inhouse DLL designed to make most (but not all as you'll see) database functions be handled the same way or easier)*

```
sbCommonFunctions.Database testDB = new sbCommonFunctions.Database();
testDB.Connect("production", "database", "user", "password");
List<string> listEventIDs = new List<string>();
List<string> listEventDetailIDs = new List<string>();
List<string> listTestInformationIDs = new List<string>();
List<string> listTestStepIDs = new List<string>();
List<string> listMeasurementIDs = new List<string>();
string dtQuery = (String.Format(@"SELECT `Events_new`.`Event_ID`
        FROM Events_new
        GROUP BY `Events_new`.`PCBID`,
        `Events_new`.`EventType_ID`,
        `Events_new`.`DateTime`,
        `Events_new`.`User`
        HAVING (((COUNT(`Events_new`.`PCBID`)) > 1)
        AND ((COUNT(`Events_new`.`User`)) > 1) 
        AND ((COUNT(`Events_new`.`DateTime`)) > 1))"));

int iterations = 0;
DataTable dtEventIDs = getDT(dtQuery, testDB);
while (dtEventIDs.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dtEventIDs.Rows.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(iterations);
    iterations++;
    foreach(DataRowView eventID in dtEventIDs.DefaultView)
    {
        listEventIDs.Add(eventID.Row[0].ToString());
        DataTable dtEventDetails = testDB.QueryDatabase(String.Format(
        "SELECT * FROM EventDetails_new WHERE Event_ID = {0}",
           eventID.Row[0]));
        foreach(DataRowView drvEventDetail in dtEventDetails.DefaultView)
        {
            listEventDetailIDs.Add(drvEventDetail.Row[0].ToString());
        }   
        DataTable dtTestInformation = testDB.QueryDatabase(String.Format(
        @"SELECT TestInformation_ID 
        FROM TestInformation_new 
        WHERE Event_ID = {0}",
            eventID.Row[0]));
        foreach(DataRowView drvTest in dtTestInformation.DefaultView)
        {
            listTestInformationIDs.Add(drvTest.Row[0].ToString());
            DataTable dtTestSteps = testDB.QueryDatabase(String.Format(
            @"SELECT TestSteps_ID 
            FROM TestSteps_new 
            WHERE TestInformation_TestInformation_ID = {0}",
               drvTest.Row[0]));
            foreach(DataRowView drvTestStep in dtTestSteps.DefaultView)
            {
                listTestStepIDs.Add(drvTestStep.Row[0].ToString());
                DataTable dtMeasurements = testDB.QueryDatabase(String.Format(
                @"SELECT Measurements_ID 
                FROM Measurements_new 
                WHERE TestSteps_TestSteps_ID = {0}",
                   drvTestStep.Row[0]));
                foreach(DataRowView drvMeasurements in dtMeasurements.DefaultView)
                {
                    listMeasurementIDs.Add(drvMeasurements.Row[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    testDB.Disconnect();
    string mysqlConnection = 
    "server=server;\ndatabase=database;\npassword=password;\nUser ID=user;";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(mysqlConnection);
    connection.Open();
    //start unwinding the duplicates from the lowest level upward
    whackDuplicates(listMeasurementIDs, "measurements_new", "Measurements_ID", connection);
    whackDuplicates(listTestStepIDs, "teststeps_new", "TestSteps_ID", connection);
    whackDuplicates(listTestInformationIDs, "testinformation_new", "testInformation_ID", connection);
    whackDuplicates(listEventDetailIDs, "eventdetails_new", "eventdetails_ID", connection);
    whackDuplicates(listEventIDs, "events_new", "event_ID", connection);
    connection.Close();
    //update iterator from inside the clause in case there are more duplicates.
    dtEventIDs = getDT(dtQuery, testDB);    }

}//goofy curly brace to allow LinqPAD to deal with inline classes
public void whackDuplicates(List<string> listOfIDs,
                            string table,
                            string pkID, 
                            MySqlConnection connection)
{
    foreach(string ID in listOfIDs)
    {
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = String.Format(
        "DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + pkID + " = {0}", ID);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
public DataTable getDT(string query, sbCommonFunctions.Database db)
{
    return db.QueryDatabase(query);
//}/*this is deliberate, LinqPAD has a weird way of dealing with inline
     classes and the last one can't have a closing curly brace (and the 
     first one has to have an extra opening curly brace above it, go figure)
   */
```

Basically this is a giant while loop, and the clause iterator is updated from inside the clause until the number of Event_ID's drops to zero (it takes 5 iterations, some of the data has as many as six duplicates).