# How can I remove duplicate records and keep only 1 copy that has the latest dateUpdated field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove all duplicates records that have have  the same `stationId` and only keep one record that has the latest `dateUpdated`

`stationId` is varchar(20)
`dateUpdated` is datetime

I usually remove duplicates this the following, but this time I don't think it will work

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1(title);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `alter table` statement *removes* records; it just ignores index creation errors.

Instead:

```
delete t
    from table t left join
         (select t.stationId, max(t.dateUpdated) as maxdu
          from table t
          group by t.stationId
         ) tmax
         on t.stationId = tmax.stationId and t.dateUpdated = tmax.maxdu
    where tmax.stationId is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.dateUpdated < t2.dateUpdated AND t1.stationId= t2.stationId
```

[Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)