# deleting duplicate posts with repeated meta_values

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have been trying to figure out how to delete duplicate posts in my Wordpress database.  More specifically, I am looking to delete all wp_posts that have the same meta_value for the meta_key "*itemID*" in the wp_postmeta table.

In other words, I don't want 2 or more posts to have nor the same title, nor the same "itemID" meta_value, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Just for reference, the queries I usually use are below.

With the first query below, I can see what meta_values are repeated, and how many times.  Additionally with the second query, I can see what posts are duplicates, only by their title (I did not come up with this one)

1.

```
SELECT meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value, COUNT( * ) 
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key =  '_itemID_'
GROUP BY meta_value
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```

2.

```
SELECT bad_rows.*
from wp_posts as bad_rows
inner join (
select post_title, MIN(id) as min_id
from wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'post'
AND post_status = 'publish'
group by post_title
having count(*) > 1
) as good_rows on good_rows.post_title = bad_rows.post_title
and good_rows.min_id <> bad_rows.id
```

Thank you for looking and merry xmas!

Comment: Have you tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

for records with duplicate title you can simply do this :

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM(SELECT id,title FROM wp_posts GROUP BY title) )
```

and for meta key word you should first join two tables and do the same.