# Delete duplicate rows with same ID number

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I noticed that I have a lot of duplicates in one of my tables.
Here's an example of how the table looks (example with one id_product_attribute number):

[image]

So I want to delete the duplicate currencies for EACH id_product_attribute.
The desired result is to have one id currency for each id_product_attribute. Which means: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 --> 5 rows per id_product and not 10 (5 duplicates).

I tried to use different codes but I can't make it work:

```
DELETE FROM product_attribute USING product_attribute, product_attribute pa
WHERE product_attribute.id_currency > pa.id_currency
AND product_attribute.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute
AND product_attribute_price.id_product_attribute = '16632'
```

So If I run the above, I will delete everything and only id_curreny 1 will stay there. I need to have:

```
Attribute Currency 
  16632    -    1
  16632    -    2
  16632    -    3
  16632    -    4
  16632    -    6
```

Can anyone help me with this? Any hint would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use a subquery with aggregation.  But you can also take the approach that you want.  Instead of a regular join, use a `left join` and check for no matches:

```
DELETE pa
    FROM product_attribute pa LEFT JOIN
         product_attribute pa2
         ON product_attribute.id_currency > pa.id_currency AND
            pa.id_product_attribute = pa2.id_product_attribute AND
    WHERE pa.id_product_attribute = '16632' AND
          pa2.id_product_attribute IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I am currently getting a syntax error "Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'pa LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa2 ON produ' at line 2 ". Will try to fix that and see if it works :) Thanks again