# How to group the column value using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need query to skip duplicate column value according to the auto increment `id` using MySQL.I am explaining my table structure below.

> db_subcat:

```
member_id      day_id

16               2

18               2

18               2

18               3
```

Here i need to skip the duplicate column value according to the `member_id` e.g- here for `member_id-18` there are two `day_id` as `2`,i need to fetch only one if `member_id` is same.

Comment: You can use `UNIQUE` key in MySQL so that duplicate results will not be inserted in the first place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `distinct`:

```
select distinct member_id, day_id from db_subcat;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `distinct` as well as `group by`

```
select distinct member_id, day_id from db_subcat;
select member_id, day_id from db_subcat group by member_id, day_id;
```

Here `distinct` will be faster than `group by`. To see the difference have a look at http://charlesnagy.info/it/mysql/difference-between-distinct-and-group-by

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UNIQUE` key in MySQL so that the duplicate results will not be inserted in the first place.

Else, you can use `SELECT distinct`:

```
SELECT distinct member_id, day_id from db_subcat;
```

More information on `SQL Unique Constraint`: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp.

More information on `SQL Select Distinct`: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from skipping the duplicate member id, you may want the sum of day_id as well, below query fetches that:

```
select member_id, sum(day_id)
from db_subcat
group by member_id
```

You can use any aggregate function (e.g. min, max, count, avg) according to the requirement.