# Delete duplicate records in MySql in one single query

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have this MySQL table:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |                                                                                                                                               
+------+------+                                                                                                                                               
|    1 | John |                                                                                                                                               
|    1 | John |                                                                                                                                               
|    2 | Jill |                                                                                                                                               
|    2 | Jill |                                                                                                                                               
|    3 | Jack |                                                                                                                                               
|    3 | Jack |                                                                                                                                               
+------+------+
```

Can anyone please tell me how to delete the duplicate records and keep one record from this table in MySQL in one single query (i.e without creating another table)?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: Hi Mattia,The id in my table is not unique. So I cannot use that query

Comment: If you don't have an uniq identifier how I think you can't only one row.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We'd like to see your attempt at solving this. Please supply your query and what it's result is. Or, show us where you searched toward solving this and why it didn't help you. "[ask]" and "[mcve]" will help.

Answer (score -1):

You have basically two options unless you want to do something more precise:

select * from table group by ID

or, alternatively:

select distinct(ID), name from table

Comment: Hi Giovanni,I want to delete one duplicate record and keep the unique record in the table