# PHP - Deleting duplicate values with same ref

Tags: php, mysql, select, duplicates

I've the following MySQL Table called **store**

```
id ref item_no supplier
1  10    x1      usa
2  10    x1      usa
3  11    x1      china
4  12    x2      uk
5  12    x3      uk
6  13    x3      uk
7  13    x3      uk
```

Now What i'm excepting the output to be is as follows :

```
id ref item_no supplier
1  10    x1      usa
3  11    x1      china
4  12    x2      uk
5  12    x3      uk
6  13    x3      uk
```

As you can see `item_no` **x1** and **x3** have same ref and supplier source, so what I want is to delete the duplicate record in-order to keep one `item_no` only !

I've create this PHP code to `SELECT` results only :

```
$query1 = "SELECT 
                DISTINCT(item_no) AS field, 
                COUNT(item_no) AS fieldCount, 
                COUNT(ref) AS refcount 
            FROM 
                store 
            GROUP BY item_no HAVING fieldCount > 1";

$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){
    while ($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        echo $row1['field']."<br /><br />";
    }
} else {
    //IGNORE
}
```

How to tell the query to `SELECT` Duplicate records properly according to my needs before creating the `DELETE` query.

Thanks Guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query to produce the required result set:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM store AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) AS id, ref, item_no
   FROM store
   GROUP BY ref, item_no
) AS t2 ON t1.id > t2.id AND t1.ref = t2.ref AND t1.item_no = t2.item_no
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66f73/2)

To `DELETE` you can use:

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM store AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) AS id, ref, item_no
   FROM store
   GROUP BY ref, item_no
) AS t2 ON t1.id > t2.id AND t1.ref = t2.ref AND t1.item_no = t2.item_no
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll try the code you have informed me with. I'll reply back shortly

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't select the duplicate. It lists all  `item_no` . Also why did you select id ? I want ref and supplier if they are the same also

Comment: @AliHamra The `SELECT` query selects everything *but* the duplicates. I thought this was your intention.

Comment: Oh my bad, I want the opposite. I want to list the duplicates

Comment: @AliHamra Please check the edit I made: `t1.id > t2.id` instead of `t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: I've used your updated answer, but now it does not list any `item_no` at all. And there is no mysql query errors too .

Comment: @AliHamra I've tested the code and it works with your sample data. You can also check the fiddle demo I've included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To find only duplicate records you can use

```
 SELECT * FROM store WHERE id NOT IN 
 (SELECT id FROM store AS outerStore WHERE id = 
 (SELECT MAX(id) FROM store AS innerStore 
 WHERE outerStore.ref = innerStore.ref AND 
 outerStore.supplier = innerStore.supplier AND outerStore.item_no = innerStore.item_no))
```

Maybe long, but it should work.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its long, the query itself is correct but it outputs empty records :(..I don't understand why

Comment: Ok I guess I found what is the problem..If I remove `outerStore.ref = innerStore.ref AND 
 outerStore.supplier = innerStore.supplier AND` from your code, it works but not what I am  expected...it only list duplicate items

Comment: It works in my local base with your data. `mysql_num_rows($result1)` return  0 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the select of the row to delete use

```
select *  from  store 
where id not in (
    select max(id)  from  store 
    group by  distinct ref, item_no, supplier);
```

Or you can directly use a command for direct delete using

```
delete from  store 
where id not in (
    select max(id)  from  store 
    group by  distinct ref, item_no, supplier);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it shows MySQL error `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource .....`

Comment: I have update the answer with the select for getting the row  candidate to delete

Comment: According to your code it seems that it should work, but i'm still getting the same mysql error :( .

Comment: Could be there is an error in tbale name .. i have update the answer .. with  proper table name