# Deleting duplicate rows with two specific column duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete duplicate rows from my database, that has the same 'input' column, and 'response' column. Right now, I have a query that SELECT all the duplicates, but I'm not sure how to write the query to delete the duplicates:

```
SELECT * , COUNT( * ) AS matches 
FROM allData 
GROUP BY input, response 
HAVING matches > 1
```

If I'm writing the DELETE query, I think it would something like

```
DELETE FROM allData WHERE blah = blah
```

^---But that doesn't let me select the 'count(*)' or 'group by', so I'm not really sure how to properly write this.

Comment: What is your primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
DELETE 
    T1
FROM allData T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT input, response
    FROM allData 
    GROUP BY input, response 
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 
) T2 ON T1.input = T2.input AND T1.response = T2.response
```

**Edited:**

```
DELETE T1
FROM allData T1
INNER JOIN allData T2 ON T1.input = T2.input AND T1.response = T2.response AND T1.id > T2.id
```

This will remain the record which has the minimum id.
And take a look of [Delete all duplicate rows except for one in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql?rq=1).

Comment: Nope. This deletes ALL the rows that have duplicates of themselves.

Comment: I need to leave ONE original not deleted.

Comment: Good thing I tried this on a test table first...lol

Comment: @frosty you want to remain which record?

Comment: `ONE original` is which record?

Comment: Reno, for example: if there are a total of three rows in the database that are duplicated of themselves, when I run this query, it deletes ALL THREE rows.

Comment: I need at least one row to not be deleted.

Comment: Is there any other column exists? Primary key column is ok

Comment: No other columns exists in the test table, except the id.

Comment: OK, that is enough.

Comment: That's just the test table though, in my original table, there are definitely more columns.

Comment: Check my **Edited** answer please.