# How can I delete duplicate records

Tags: database, opencart

Sorry if this has already been answered but I cannot find the solution I am looking for.

I am not great with coding but know a bit but cannot figure this out

I have an opencart database and sometimes get duplicate records/products imported and what I am trying to do is schedule a task to delete any duplicates records leaving the original/first record in the database.  So delete any new records that are duplicates.

Is this possible? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show examples of the records and what you mean by duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart is an online store management system. It is PHP-based, using a **MySQL database** and HTML components.

In MySQL you have a specific topic regarding duplicate rows removal:

[Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)