# Finding duplicates and delete them in MYSQL Server

Tags: mysql

I have many duplicates of **name** and i need to find and delete them.
I want to save only highest value of **usedpoints** and delete duplicates with lower value of **usedpoints**.

MYSQL Table Example:

```
==============================
| name | points | usedpoints |
|----------------------------|
| john | 840    | 1200       |
| john | 230    | 900        |
| jane | 550    | 400        |
| jane | 130    | 245        |
| nick | 130    | 123        |
| nick | 90     | 200        |
==============================
```

Comment: Are you doing this in Sql Server or mysql?  The tags don't match the title.

Comment: Sorry, mysql (edited)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to keep the row with the lowest id value:

```
DELETE n1 FROM names n1, names n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name
```

2) If you want to keep the row with the highest id value:

```
DELETE n1 FROM names n1, names n2 WHERE n1.id < n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name
```

you can use any other filed instead of id.

Comment: I don't understand..    DELETE name FROM myTable

Comment: check this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_Number() to remove dupes

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By Name Order by usedpoints Desc)
     From  YourTable
)
--Delete from cte where RN>1
Select * from cte where RN>1   -- << Remove is satisfied
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use your_schema;

drop table if exists temp_names_values; -- names with max usedpoints will be stored in this table
create temporary table temp_names_values as (select name,max(usedpoints ) as mx from test group by name);

drop table if exists temp_max_ids ; -- record ids of names with max usedpoints will be stored in this table
create temporary table temp_max_ids  as (select test.idtest from test,temp_names_values where (test.name = temp_names_values.name and test.usedpoints = temp_names_values.mx));

select * from test where test.idtest not in (select idtest from temp_max_ids )
```

I considered that table name is test.
the last select statement is actually where you should write your delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.name, oc.dupeCount, o.usedpoints from MyTable o inner join ( SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount FROM MyTable GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) oc on o.name = oc.name
```

I have this to find duplicates, but now i need to delete them ..