# Remove duplicate rows from MySql

Tags: mysql

This is my mysqSql table.

```
m_Id |  m_Mobile |  m_ReceiveFromBranch
________________________________________
1       12345       1
2       12345       5
3       12345       1   //->Duplicate of m_Id 1
4       99999       1
5       88888       2
6       88888       5
7       88888       2   //->Duplicate of m_Id 5
```

...

How can I delete only duplicate rows? I have more that 10 thousand rows with many duplicates.

Comment: You can follow this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: @BikashPaul I want to keep the rows with  `m_Mobile` with distinct `m_ReceiveFromBranch`

Comment: Usually you'd solve this with an exists clause, but I am not able to post my answer anymore. Anyway, the solution linked to works, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 DELETE a
FROM mytable  as a, mytable  as b
WHERE
  (a.m_mobile   = b.m_mobile )
AND (a.m_ReceiveFromBranch = b.m_ReceiveFromBranch )
AND a.ID < b.ID;
```

Comment: How can I delete ?

Comment: Check : DELETE a
FROM mytable  as a, mytable  as b
WHERE
  (a.m_mobile   = b.m_mobile )
AND (a.m_ReceiveFromBranch = b.m_ReceiveFromBranch )
AND a.ID < b.ID;