# Mysql Partition error

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a mysql script that will search for results while at the same time filtering out duplicates of a particular field, I did some research and the code I found came in the format of something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sites s INNER JOIN (SELECT h.*, row_number() over (PARTITION by muleid) as seqnum from history h ) h WHERE acceptid=2;
```

But it came up with the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION by muleid) as seqnum from history h ) h WHERE acceptid=2' at line 1
```

Is there anyone that can help?

Comment: MySQL does not support window functions.

Comment: Check below post.                                                                                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: +karan arora I am not trying to remove duplicate rows, I am simply trying to figure out how to filter them out of the query results.