# delet distince data from table in php

Tags: php, mysql

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS1t3.png)

In these picture you can show one sql table in these table i have a coloum which name is "matrix_unique_id" in thst coloum i have many same id and in each id i store one image the image coloum name is    image_path.
Now i want to delete all the image in one unique id accept one image.For example:
in these 6665682 id i have 25 images now i want to delete all images accept one means when execute the query it delete 24 images and left one.

what i do?

Comment: Which one do you want to remain?

Comment: any random image

Comment: please show us the complete table

Comment: _“what i do?”_ – how about: Research …? https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+delete+duplicates

Comment: i upload a pic here

Comment: I didn't see any image

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS1t3.png

Comment: click on these link u show the image

Comment: see the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `delete join`:

```
delete t1
from yourtable t1
join yourtable t2
on t1.matrix_unique_id = t2.matrix_unique_id
and t1.id < t2.id
```

this will leave the `max(id)` of each `matrix_unique_id`.

**Edit:** If you want to leave min id, try to change

```
and t1.id < t2.id
```

to

```
and t1.id > t2.id
```

Comment: this is won't work since he have many same id in the table

Comment: sorry, I just saw his pic, this should works

Comment: @vinaykapoor Just table alias.

Comment: but when i execute these query one error occured

Comment: @vinaykapoor What is error?

Comment: it is work perfectlly ,data delete from table but what i do to delete the image from the folder where i store all my images.

Comment: @vinaykapoor Mysql can not delete the file on your local disk.

Comment: i know that but i write a php script when i run that script i want to delete image from database and also from my folder.

Comment: @vinaykapoor Then this  is another question.

Comment: k nop.Can u explain me in these query how the join work

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: @vinaykapoor Except reserved word, I think anything is OK.

Comment: "DELETE FROM rr2s4_cma_images WHERE matrix_unique_id='$matrix[$i]'";  i write these query or delete the data from table now i want to remain only one data which have minimum id than wt i do in these query?In these query first select distinct data from database and after that i delete the data but it delete all data from database.

Comment: @vinaykapoor See **Edit** part. And answer from Morgan is upvoted, why don't you just use his? :-|

Comment: Is it possible to delete all data except min id from database without using delete join?

Comment: You mean subquery? @vinaykapoor

Comment: yes if it is possible then give me solution about subquery

Comment: "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE matrix_unique_id='$matrix[$i]'";   I write these query but it delete all data from table

Comment: Any answer for that?

Comment: You accept answer then cancel accept, then accept again, now cancel accept again, please don't be so rude. By your such manner, I've lost patient about your question. @vinaykapoor

Comment: I really apologized for that i didn't do that ./my friend did it.Once again i said sorry.