# Laravel - Deleting Duplicate Rows in SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to delete rows in my SQL database that have the same `norad_cat_id`. Because the data in my database will update everyday, new rows with the same `norad_cat_id` will be added. What I want to do is to delete all the rows the have the same `norad_cat_id` and only leave the most recently added one. So far I have tried a few solutions from Stack Overflow (none of which worked):

**1:**

```
DB::table('satellites')->select('norad_cat_id')->distinct()->delete();
```

**2:**

```
$deleteDuplicates = DB::table('satellites as n1')
    ->join('satellites as n2', 'n1.norad_cat_id', '>', 'norad_cat_id')
    ->where('n1.norad_cat_id', '=', 'n2.norad_cat_id')
    ->delete();
```

My database name is `satellite`.

**TL;DR:** Delete rows that have the same `norad_cat_id` in my database

**EDIT:**

Here is my full function:

```
    public function displayer(){
    $api = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.space-track.org',
    'cookies' => true, 
    ]); $api->post('ajaxauth/login', [
      'form_params' => [
         'identity' => '#', 
         'password' => '#', 
     ],
    ]);
    $response = $api->get('basicspacedata/query/class/satcat/orderby/INTLDES%20desc/limit/2/metadata/false');
    $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    foreach ($data as $attributes) {
        $attributes = array_change_key_case($attributes, CASE_LOWER);
        Satellite::create($attributes);
    }
    $deleteDuplicates = DB::table('satellites as n1') 
      ->join('satellites as n2', 'n1.created_at', '<', 'n2.created_at') 
        ->where('n1.created_at', '=', 'n2.created_at') ->delete();
    $api->get('ajaxauth/logout');
    return redirect('/');   
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think I need to give a clear explanation of what I am trying to achieve: My database will update automatically. What I want to be able to do is to create a row if the `norad_cat_id` does not already exist in the database. If it already exists, I want it to take the row with the same `norad_cat_id`, delete it and only leave the most recent row using the timestamps I have in my database. So that I have one of each `norad_cat_id`.

I was looking at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#deleting-models and https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries. Maybe I can use this?

**EDIT 2:**
Can anyone shed some light on this code I wrote:

```
DB::select( DB::raw('DELETE n1 FROM satellites n1, satellites n2 WHERE n1.id < n2.id AND n1.norad_cat_id = n2.norad_cat_id'));
```

I looked at some answers and other questions and tried coming up with something.

Comment: Have you any primary key or unique id in your table?

Comment: choose between mysql or sql-server, you cannot have both

Comment: can u try to run raw sql in Laravel ? such as 

DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = '$someVariable'") );

Look how to delete duplicate rows on mysql; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: are you using timestamps? would be easy if you are using them

Comment: @aaron0207, Yes I am using timestamps, so I guess you could use them

Comment: what about your second method whats the error ? `$deleteDuplicates = DB::table('satellites as n1')
    ->join('satellites as n2', 'n1.norad_cat_id', '>', 'norad_cat_id')
    ->where('n1.norad_cat_id', '=', 'n2.norad_cat_id')
    ->delete();`

Comment: @ArunpandianM - Tried your code, got an error - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'norad_cat_id' in on clause is ambiguous

Comment: @GuidoG I am using mysql

Comment: @D.777KLM found the bug in your second query check my answer and let me know whether its working or not

Comment: @D.777KLM Than remove the sql-server tag please I have done it for you this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at some other answers I found the one that best works for me:

```
DELETE FROM satellites WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(n.id) FROM satellites n GROUP BY n.norad_cat_id) x)
```

This deletes all rows with the same `norad_cat_id` but leaves one with the highest `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it will keep only the duplicate and non-duplicate id lastest id and

```
$deleteDuplicates = DB::table('satellites as n1') 
  ->join('satellites as n2', 'n1.norad_cat_id', '<', 'n2.norad_cat_id') 
    ->where('n1.norad_cat_id', '=', 'n2.norad_cat_id') ->delete();
```

in response to OP comment :

> got an error - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052
>   Column 'norad_cat_id' in on clause is ambiguous

Which Means you have to specify which table the column refers...

reference : [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

**EDIT**

```
$ids_to_delete = array(1, 2, 3);
DB::table('satellites')->whereIn('norad_cat_id', $ids_to_delete)->delete();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this still does not delete duplicate row. There is no more error now.

Comment: do you get any error ? can you create a `sqlfiddle` ?

Comment: I will post my full model now

Comment: remove `delete` and instead put `get` and check the output whether its returning something or check is that the `array` you want to `delete`

Comment: There is an output of the rows I want

Comment: your result is in single dimensional or multidimensional array ?

Comment: Single Dimensional

Comment: check my updated answer try it if possible else we will move it to chat for further conversation

Comment: No that did not work. Everything works except the delete old rows with the same `norad_cat_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150410/discussion-between-arun-pandian-m-and-d-777klm).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using timestamps:

```
$target_data = DB::table('satellites')->select('norad_cat_id')->where('norad_cat_id',$id_to_delete)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

$i = 0;
$len = count($target_data );

foreach($target_data as $data){
    if ($i != $len - 1) {
        $data->delete();
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Wait, didn't read about multiple records with same id, thought there will be only 2 records with the same id EDIT: done!

Comment: I tried this - got an Undefined variable. What do you mean by `$id_to_delete`?

Comment: Initialize it with the desired id to get clean of duplicates (you can use it after insert a new record with the desired id, for example)

Comment: I tried adding `$norad_cat_id` but I still get the same error

Comment: When I said initialize I mean something like $norad_cat_id = 1; (supposing that this field is integer)

Comment: Oh, Never thought about that. That fixed the error, but still does not delete the row.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this :

```
$delSatellite = DB::table('satellites')->select('norad_cat_id')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

foreach($delSatellites as $delSatellite){
  DB::table('satellites')->where('id',$delSatellite->id)->delete();

}
```

Hope this work for you!!!

Comment: This deletes all rows in my database. I might have been doing something wrong. I will see what I can do.