# Delete duplicate rows but maintain many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I'm saving the results from my Tensorflow image classifier in a SQL database. I have 3 tables. Images, Categories and a table joining the two with weight variables. Some images have no relationships and some have lots.

The problem is that I have duplicate rows in the image table that need to be removed. But I need to preserve the many to many relationships, if the duplicated image has one or more.

Here's an example:

Table name: **my_images**

```
+----+------------+-----------------+
| ID | image_path | image_filename  |
+----+------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Film 1     | Film 1 001.jpg  |
|  2 | Film 1     | Film 1 001.jpg  |
|  3 | Film 1     | Film 1 002.jpg  |
|  4 | Film 1     | Film 1 002.jpg  |
|  5 | Film 1     | Film 1 003.jpg  |
|  6 | Film 1     | Film 1 003.jpg  |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

Table name: **my_terms**

```
+---------+------------+
| term_id | term_name  |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | cat        |
|       2 | dog        |
|       3 | automobile |
+---------+------------+
```

Table name: **my_term_relationships**

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| image_id | term_id | weight  |
+----------+---------+---------+
|        2 |       1 | 0.58516 |
|        2 |       3 | 0.16721 |
|        3 |       2 | 0.21475 |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

So in this example, the ideal outcome would be to delete rows 1, 4 and either row 5 or 6 from **my_images**.

Comment: I wouldn't post an answer as it's been a long time since I've done real sql queries. 

I would start by creating a query that delete dups, like the 2nd most populare answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Then i'd add in to the subquery that the selected id has to exist in your my_term_relationships.

Hope it helps

Comment: By the way, is it possible that the same image_filename is referenced under different ids in `my_term_relationships` ? If yes, then my above proposition will not work. In this case I'd advice to first 'clean up' your `my_terms_relationships` table in order to only have one image_id per image_filename in this table. Then my above comment will be relevant I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach this step by step.

First, find the duplicate entries:

```
SELECT 
image_path, image_filename
FROM my_images
GROUP BY image_path, image_filename
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Second, get all rows that are duplicate:

```
SELECT mi.*
FROM my_images mi
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    image_path, image_filename
    FROM my_images
    GROUP BY image_path, image_filename
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dups ON mi.image_path = dups.image_path AND mi.image_filename = dups.image_filename
```

Finally, get the IDs not to delete.

```
SELECT MIN(ID)
FROM my_images mi
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    image_path, image_filename
    FROM my_images
    GROUP BY image_path, image_filename
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dups ON mi.image_path = dups.image_path AND mi.image_filename = dups.image_filename
LEFT JOIN my_term_relationships mtr ON mi.ID = mtr.image_id
WHERE mtr.image_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY mi.image_path, mi.image_filename
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/470cdd/7/0)

Check if everything is correct. If yes, convert it into a delete statement.

```
DELETE my_images.* FROM my_images 
JOIN (
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID
FROM my_images mi
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    image_path, image_filename
    FROM my_images
    GROUP BY image_path, image_filename
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dups ON mi.image_path = dups.image_path AND mi.image_filename = dups.image_filename
LEFT JOIN my_term_relationships mtr ON mi.ID = mtr.image_id
WHERE mtr.image_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY mi.image_path, mi.image_filename
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
) sq USING(ID);
```

- sqlfiddle with delete statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed63de/1/0

EDIT: to also fix the problem that Logar mentioned, use this UPDATE statement before the DELETE statement.

```
UPDATE my_term_relationships mtr 
JOIN (
    SELECT mi.ID, minID
    FROM my_images mi
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
        image_path, image_filename, MIN(ID) AS minID
        FROM my_images
        GROUP BY image_path, image_filename
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) dups ON mi.image_path = dups.image_path AND mi.image_filename = dups.image_filename
) sq ON mtr.image_id = sq.ID 
SET mtr.image_id = sq.minID;
```

- see it all working together in this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/268539/1/0

Comment: Again, I believe if you have two ids referencing the same filename in `my_term_relationships` you will keep the dups in `my_images`, I'd add a first query that updates the ids in `my_term_relationhips` : To see what I mean, in your fiddle, change the values for 
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0.58516),
    (2, 3, 0.16721),
    (3, 2, 0.21475);

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But when I try the delete query I get the error "You can't specify target table 'my_images' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: @Logar Fixed your concern, too. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @fancyPants but I'm getting the error "Duplicate entry '87949-4' for key 'PRIMARY'" when I run your update query.

Comment: @fancyPants Perfect. I've dropped the private keys and it works beautifully. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @DavidApple You're welcome. Feel free to accept (and/or upvote) my answer. Would be appreciated and others know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query two set of image ID's, and make a filter with them. Assuming `image_path` and `image_filename` is UNIQUE together:

1. All `my_images` ID, that is not referenced by `my_term_relationships`, but a corresponding `image_path`+`image_filename` might be referenced.
2. Unique ID's, which belongs to `image_path`+`image_filename` pairs, that is not referenced at all in `my_term_relationships`.

Take a look at this query:

```
DELETE FROM my_images 
WHERE 
   ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT image_id FROM my_term_relationships) -- 1
   AND 
   ID NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT MIN(ID) as id
    FROM my_images 
    LEFT JOIN my_term_relationships ON ID = image_id
     GROUP BY image_path,image_filename
     HAVING COUNT(image_id) = 0
   ) as u_ids -- 2
);
```

Note, that you must wrap the `my_images` table in the DELETE's WHERE clause in a sub-query. Read this thread for explanation: [Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Example: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c4e3e/3)

---

Example update query for removing duplicate rows from `my_term_relationships`:

```
UPDATE my_term_relationships
SET image_id = (
  select min(my_images.ID) 
  from my_images 
  join my_images as ref_image on (my_images.image_path = ref_image.image_path and my_images.image_filename = ref_image.image_filename)
  where ref_image.ID = image_id
 );
```

Comment: I still have a few duplicate image_path + image_filename pairs after running this query. Perhaps I have rows in my_term_relationships that point to duplicated images. Is there a way to merge these?

Comment: Then you need to run an UPDATE on my_term_relationships before you delete the rows.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. But I'm getting the error "Column 'image_id' cannot be null" when I run the update query.