# deleting duplicate rows in single given column in mysql without any ids

Tags: mysql

```
EMP
-------
EMPNO
-----------
1
1
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
6
```

Write a `DELETE` statement to delete the duplicate rows.  After running your `Delete` statement, one occurrence of each value of `Empno` should remain in the table.

Comment: what you tried so far....?

Comment: delete a from emp1 a where empno in(select empno from ( select empno  from emp1 group by empno having count(empno)>1) as net) ;

Comment: i am beginner in this, can do simple operations in mysql and mongodb not the very complex one

Comment: I given answer and one link too you can try that

Comment: yeah i have seen this link before but there we have distinct id to compare but not here

Comment: This hypothetical problem could not occur in a normalised environment. Therefore, I reject the premise  of the question.

Comment: You can't write delete query for this because you don't have a unique id or timestamp

Comment: ok sir thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

simplest thing is define **unique constraint on that column** so it will not take duplicate values and if there are then it will auto delete

Or Try below query

```
DELETE e.*
FROM emp1 e
WHERE empno IN
 (SELECT empno
   FROM (SELECT MIN(e1.empno) as empno
          FROM emp1 e1
          GROUP BY e1.empno
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x);
```

Or you can see this example also [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

Comment: not working, empno in group statement is ambiguous.....this deleted all duplicates

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: is that worked for you? if not then please share DB structure with values

Comment: create table EMP1 (EMPNO numeric(2) not null);
insert into EMP1 values(1);
insert into EMP1 values(1);
insert into EMP1 values(2);
insert into EMP1 values(3);
insert into EMP1 values(3);
insert into EMP1 values(4);
insert into EMP1 values(4);
insert into EMP1 values(4);
insert into EMP1 values(5);
insert into EMP1 values(6);
select * from emp1;
DELETE e.*
FROM emp1 e
WHERE empno IN
 (SELECT empno
   FROM (SELECT MIN(empno) as empno
          FROM emp1
          GROUP BY empno
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) x);
use mtech;

Comment: are we able to do this in other sql like oracle?

Comment: @pankaj Why would we?

Comment: i mean may be there some clauses which are there to solve it but not in mysql

Comment: why you need such table with one column I have no idea....simplest thing is define unique constraint on that column so it will not take duplicate values and if there are then it will auto .delete

Comment: @pankaj But the problem is so specific and improbable.

Comment: yeah i understand you

Comment: I don't think you do :-(

Comment: @Naincy if you believe that another SO question already has the answer for the current one, then flag it as a duplicate, do not answer!