# MySQL: Delete Duplicate entries from a row not working

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am trying to use the following code to remove duplicate entries from a column called herit. The name of my table is people

```
DELETE FROM people
 WHERE herit NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MIN(n.herit)
                            FROM people n
                        GROUP BY n.herit) x)
```

Although this code is executed and it states "5 rows affected", it doesn't remove duplicates from my table in mysql.

What could possibly be wrong? I searched all over the internet, couldn't find anything satisfactory

Comment: _didn't commit your transaction?_ Where do you see any transactions? @shadowsheep

Comment: You need to remove duplicate row or only column value???Please clear.

Comment: If you do `select * from people where herit not in...` do you get the row you wanna delete?

Comment: @B001 removed and added a new comment.

Comment: I need to remove all the rows which contain similar values for the column named herit @Sumit

Comment: @shadowsheep  no I do not get those rows

Comment: So that's the reason. You must have the right query that shows you all the rows you wanna delete. Then transform it in a delete statement.

Comment: Do you use Primary Id for this table?

Comment: Your group by is probably not returning what you want can you add sample data and expected output to your question as text. And what's a herit other than  an Ancient Egyptian princess of the Second Intermediate Period?

Comment: Does this find the `herit`s you want to delete? `SELECT n.herit FROM people n GROUP BY n.herit HAVING count(*) > 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one..

```
DELETE FROM people WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM people GROUP BY herit HAVING count(herit) > 1 
OR count(herit) = 1) newTable)
```

[image]
                                                                          [image]

This is actual and resultant table

Comment: Couldn't it be simplified to `DELETE FROM people WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM people GROUP BY herit)`?

Comment: No delete operation is not perform with same table using nested query. So we need to fool the mysql..