# Mysql query for removing rows having duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, duplicates

I want to delete all rows which has duplicate entries and I do not want to keep the single one of each. I wish to remove all entries having duplicate entries. Here I referred some code which will keep highest or lowest id value. All queries here will remain a single entry from duplicate records

`Mysql` Query I tried is

```
DELETE * ,count(*)as n FROM cart by rfid HAVING n>1
```

DB design :

```
ID(PK)|RFID    |CATAGORY                                                       
1     |1       |5                                                                                           
2     | 1      | 5                                                                                        
3     | 2      | 4                                                                                       
4     |3       | 6
```

Output:

```
ID(PK)|RFID|CATAGORY                                                                       
2     | 1      | 5                                                                                        
3     | 2      | 4                                                                                       
4     |3       | 6
```

Expected Result:

```
ID(PK)|RFID|CATAGORY                                                               
 3     | 2      | 4                                                                                        
 4     |3       | 6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: I think this question is duplicate try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: But it will not delete all records, will remain a single entry having duplicate values. I wish to delete complete records having duplicate entries

Comment: I didn't get the real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select distinct and oldest entries (**Note:** using MIN() and assuming id is autoincrement mode and PK) , just switch to MAX() to preserve newest instead.

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM cart group by rfid;
```

All together (deleting all that where not in previous select

```
DELETE FROM cart where id NOT in (SELECT MIN(id) FROM cart group by rfid);
```

The above wont work because You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause (DELETE in this case), but you can trickit around by a subselect, so the final working query would be:

```
DELETE FROM cart WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(A.id) FROM (SELECT * FROM cart) A group by A.rfid);
```

**Edit** (to remove all entries that have a count>1 )

```
DELETE FROM cart WHERE id  IN( 
  SELECT A.id FROM (SELECT * FROM cart) A where A.rfid IN 
  (SELECT B.rfid from  (SELECT * FROM cart) B group by B.rfid having count(B.rfid)>1)
);
```

Comment: Look at the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE cart.* FROM cart INNER JOIN (SELECT rfid,catagory FROM cart GROUP BY rfid,catagory HAVING COUNT(*)>1) dup ON cart.rfid = dup.rfid AND cart.`catagory` = dup.`catagory`
```

This query solved my problem.thank u