# delete duplicates in sql lite from one table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to delete duplicates form my table in database.

```
Databasename - >  urls
Table - > url
```

I tried this, but its not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 url
FROM
 urls;
```

Table structure:

```
url    website    checked
```

Comment: Show us your sql code

Comment: This link may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685173/2893413

Comment: Add your table structure some table results which has duplicates.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: It's unclear if you are using SQLite or MySQL. They are two different products.

Comment: Sqlite.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a temporary table to make it easier for yourself to actually remove the duplicates from the table.

```
CREATE TABLE urls_temp 
LIKE urls;

INSERT INTO urls_temp
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM urls
GROUP BY url;

DROP TABLE urls;

ALTER TABLE urls_temp 
RENAME TO urls;
```

If you just want to get the data out of the database hiding the duplicates you can just do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM urls;
```

However in the long run you can ensure uniqueness by putting a constraint on the column or making it a primary key to stop anymore duplicates from being entered in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `SELECT` from a database. You perform a query to read rows from a table, this is why your query is wrong in the way that you're trying to select a table from database.

This is not how it's done. You should connect to a database and then select columns from a table.

Let's say you have duplicates in column `website` stored within table `url` residing in database `urls`, so first you would connect to your database, assuming you are using command line tool (if that's not the case, just choose it in your graphical query tool):

```
USE urls; -- for MySQL
.open "urls.db" -- for SQLite
```

Then select unique websites from url table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT website
FROM url;
```

If you need to return unique rows (not one column values) then use `*`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 'url' is your table name, so it should come after the keyword 'FROM'

Something like this:

select distinct * from url;

Answer (score 0):

SQL query to delete duplicate `websites` from `url` table, the table must have unique field - id

```
DELETE FROM url 
WHERE
    id NOT IN (SELECT 
                id
              FROM
                    (SELECT 
                        id
                    FROM
                        url
                    GROUP BY website
                    ) AS x
               )
```