# Delete Duplicate Records

Tags: mysql

How would I delete all duplicate data from a MySQL Table, without altering / adding any extra column?

```
SELECT * FROM webs;

+--------+
|  web   |
+--------+  
| google |
| google | 
| msn    |
| yahoo  |   
| msn    |
| yahoo  |
+--------+
```

Result should be:

```
+--------+
|  web   |
+--------+
| google |
| yahoo  | 
| msn    |
+--------+
```

Comment: Is that the entire schema of your `webs` table? Do you want to remove the duplicate entries from the table, or just from the query you're running?

Comment: Yes want to delete duplicate entries and retain only single entry of each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: That is case Sql Sever, In Mysql don't have rowid

Comment: Is there any other column in `webs`? In MySQL, you can't delete duplicates without adding/altering columns or creating temp table since there is no `rowid` or `rownum`. If there is any other `unique` column in your table then we can do it

Comment: No bro don't have any other column, Operation need to be done with respect to given data.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this through a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp SELECT DISTINCT * FROM webs;
DROP TABLE webs;
ALTER TABLE temp RENAME TO webs;
```

Comment: Cannot Alter / Create temp table. Operation need to be performed on same table.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE d1 FROM `webs` d1 
INNER JOIN `webs` d2
WHERE d1.column_name = d2.column_name AND d1.id>d2.id;
```

Hope this would help. This will check a single column as your table has a single column for duplication check. Replace column_name with the actual column name.

**EDIT:**

If the table has only single column

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `webs` ADD UNIQUE(web)
```

Comment: This delete all rows of Table, need to retains distinct rows.

Comment: if you can add an id column to your table, then we can delete the items with higher id value adding  `AND where d1.id>d2.id`

Comment: You have single column to your table? @Zero

Comment: Operation need to be performed on same table. New column or Temp table cannot be used.

Comment: Cannot Alter table.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT web
FROM table_name;

**UPD**

INSERT INTO tempTableName(cellId,attributeId,entityRowId,value)
    SELECT DISTINCT cellId,attributeId,entityRowId,value
    FROM tableName;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5016434/8483171

Comment: Duplicate need to be Deleted.

Comment: Operation need to be done on same table, Table cannot be altered or cannot use temp tables.

Comment: @Zero then it is impossible, I think. But this variant is good. Select all distinct, then just replace data in the table.