# Insert or Update with mysql if same two column

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

I have a table to store client's answers.I want to use one mysql query to insert or update this table.
My Table name : questionform_answer
and columns >  ClientID QuestionID OptionID

Each client can only have one same question id.For example

```
 ClientID QuestionID OptionID
    1         1         1
    1         2         5
    2         1         3
```

I want to update OptionID if already exist ClientID and QuestionID.I don't want to use select query so taking so time.
I tried

```
     ON KEY UPDATE
     Replace Into
```

But I could not.
I use php so I tried first update query and if mysqli return fail insert row but it is also slow.
MY insert and update code :

```
   Insert Into questionform_answer (ClientID,QuestionID,OptionID) values 
   ('$ClientID','$soruid','$cevapid')


   Update questionform_answer set OptionID='$cevapid' where 
   ClientID='$ClientID' and QuestionID='$soruid'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this is to add a unique key over `(ClientID, QuestionID)` and use an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (ClientID, QuestionID);

INSERT INTO table1
VALUES (1, 1, 4)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
OptionID = VALUES(OptionID)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQNCdVcskDUsj8xjjkPEPp/0)

Comment: How can I delete Duplicate entry for this client id and question id ? @Nick

Comment: @johnny003 do you have existing duplicates in the table?

Comment: Yes.I want to use old table with record but existing dublicates @Nick

Comment: @johnny003 this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Comment: OKey I remove it with exel

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections.
If you have a unique key  on (ClientID,QuestionID), you can do INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY like this:

```
INSERT INTO questionform_answer (ClientID,QuestionID,OptionID) 
            values ('$ClientID','$soruid','$cevapid') 
on duplicate key update OptionID='$cevapid'
```