# Delete rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need to delete from my table (TABLE_X) rows that have multiple **id_B** but preserving the only one that have the greatest value of **id_A**. The image below could be more exhaustive.
I want to delete only the highlighted rows.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_X
 WHERE id_A NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.id_A)
                            FROM TABLE_X n
                        GROUP BY n.id_B) x)
```

Note that the answer is taken from the following thread:
[Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks It works. This is what I am looking for. I had some problems with SELECT in DELETE operation