# How to delete all duplicate rows (except the first one) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I just bumped into this topic;

[Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

This almost fits my needs. But I have 2 tables which contain some (linked) duplicate rows.

The first, main table is "messages". First, before I delete anything, I would like to select them:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` n1, `messages` n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.datetime = n2.datetime AND n1.message = n2.message
```

Secondly, I have the table "labels" in whoch the rows have their own id, but also a link towards the first table, which is msgid. So, messages.id = labels.msgid

The mentioned query finds all duplicates. How to show also the linked rows in the second table?

Comment: Just add the other table to the join.

Comment: Please learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the duplicate rows from both tables and keep only the rows with the minimum `id` in `messages` you should join `labels` to your query but link it only to the duplicate rows which belong to the aliased table `n1`.
So to select all duplicate rows that must be deleted from both tables:

```
SELECT n1.*, l.*
FROM messages n1 
INNER JOIN messages n2 
ON n1.id > n2.id AND n1.datetime = n2.datetime AND n1.message = n2.message
INNER JOIN labels l
ON l.msgid = n1.id;
```

and to delete the duplicates from both tables:

```
DELETE n1, l 
FROM messages n1 
INNER JOIN messages n2 
ON n1.id > n2.id AND n1.datetime = n2.datetime AND n1.message = n2.message
INNER JOIN labels l
ON l.msgid = n1.id;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fa7c06e39bc66a6d0cb7da3eb2327620).

Answer (score 0):

Add the other table to the join. You'll need to join twice to get the label of both messages in the pair.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages AS m1
JOIN messages AS m2 ON m1.id > m2.id AND m1.datetime = m2.datetime
JOIN labels AS l1 ON l1.msgid = m1.id
JOIN labels AS l2 ON l2.msgid = m2.id
```