# Make database column data unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to alter an existing MySQL table to enforce a uniqueness constraint, but the data in the table currently is not unique.

Is there a way to modify **only** the set of duplicated data while leaving the rest unaffected? I don't want to delete the offending records as the rest of the data in the table is valuable.

Example:

```
> SELECT id, email from my_table;
+--------------------------------------+----------------+
| id                                   | email          |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+
| 070d5788-428e-4444-bd15-00b60f335bd6 | test@email.com |
| 0a81ae48-8900-4444-86da-d9418ea2ca00 | test@email.com |
| 0df1e66d-0053-4444-9774-c7daf5652d54 | test@email.com |
| 130fce57-178e-4444-b2cb-1c5c2c29fe07 | test@email.com |
...
```

SQL to run:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE (email);
```

Comment: I'd recommend creating a new table (`my_table_new`) with this constraint and containing only unique data (something like `INSERT INTO my_table_new SELECT DISTINCT id, email FROM my_table` [though you'd likely want to define an order on this to ensure consistent results), then rename `my_table` to `my_table_old`, and then finally `my_table_new` to `my_table` so any previous query to `my_table` won't need to be updated.

Comment: Also see [delete duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql),

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.  And not really easy to do.  But, what you *can* do is the following:

- Add a new column in the table with a default of "1".
- Update the existing values to a sequential number for each email.
- Then add a unique constraint.

This will allow you to keep your current data.  And prevent duplicates on new data, including not allowing duplicates between new emails and existing emails.

So:

```
alter table my_table add email_counter int default 1;

update my_table t join
       (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by id) as seqnum
        from my_table t
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set email_counter = seqnum;

create unique index unq_my_table_email_email_counter on email(email_counter);
```

Then, when you insert a new email, the counter will have a value of "1" (don't reset it in the insert!).  If the email is already in the table, you will have a unique index violation.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the offending rows of data:

```
SELECT email, CONCAT("'", GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR "','"), "'")
FROM my_table
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1;
```

These are the records that need to be updated.

It looks like the `id` column is a UUID, which should be unique already. We can use the data in this column to seed the new unique email address. e.g. `070d5788-428e-4444-bd15-00b60f335bd6@email.com`

Update the records using the following:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET email = CONCAT(id, '@email.com')
WHERE id IN (
  <ids_pasted_from_previous_output>
);
```

After this has been run, the data should be unique and the table can be altered to enforce the uniqueness constraint.