# Delete duplicate rows but keep one without having a uniqe column

Tags: mysql, sql, magento2

I have a table with duplicate entries which I want to remove, keeping none but one of the duplicate entries. As you can see, they are exactly the same in every colum, there's no way to differentiate them:

[image]

I've used this query to figure out how many duplicates I have:

```sql
select url_rewrite_id, category_id, product_id, count(*) cnt
from catalog_url_rewrite_product_category
group by url_rewrite_id, category_id, product_id
having cnt > 1
order by cnt desc
```

I could use a variant of this to remove all duplicates:

```sql
delete
from catalog_url_rewrite_product_category
where url_rewrite_id in (
    select url_rewrite_id
    from catalog_url_rewrite_product_category
    group by url_rewrite_id, category_id, product_id
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

The problem I have with this is it would remove *all* entries that are duplicates and wouldn't keep the last one.

Earlier questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3311903/10924593) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685173/10924593)) assume a unique `id` column of sorts which is not the case with the data structure I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried one of the solutions I read in the thread you shared ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql))?

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE jobs
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (site_id, title, company);
```

I think this would work.

Comment: I was just about to post this! That does indeed work.

Full query that worked for me was:

`alter ignore table catalog_url_rewrite_product_category add unique index tmp_remove_key(url_rewrite_id, category_id, product_id)`