# Delete every 2nd duplicate row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've some duplicate rows in my MySQL database-

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id |  eiin   |  level  |   post_id  |  sub_id  |
--------------------------------------------------    
| 15 | 100003  |    2   |      5     |    301    |   //want to keep this
--------------------------------------------------    
| 65 | 100003  |    2   |      5     |    301    |   //want to delete this
--------------------------------------------------
| 40 | 100003  |    3   |      17    |    105    |   //want to keep this
--------------------------------------------------    
| 73 | 100003  |    3   |      17    |    105    |   //want to delete this
--------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to delete every 2nd duplicate rows as stated in the above figure.

I can't figure out the SQL. Any help?

> This SO has my answer-
> [Delete all Duplicate Rows except for One in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql)

Comment: Isn't there a primary key in the table?

Comment: @forpas Yes, there is primary key. Updated table

Comment: Can you delete any of the duplicated rows, or you must keep the first one?