# MySQL select records for duplicates using multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like the select records from a table, or insert them into a new blank table where multiple of the columns is the same as another record in the database. The problem is similar to this Question.
[Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)
However that only compares one column. Also, one of my columns, lets say column C in the example below, is an integer. Like the question in the link above, I want each of the rows to be returned. Unforunately I am just not familiar enough with how joins work to figure this out on my own yet. I know that the code below doesn't resemble the actual SQL code need at all, it is just the clearest way I can think to describe the comparisons I am trying to get.

```
SELECT ColumnE, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC from table where (
  Row1.ColumnA = Row2.ColumnA &&
  Row1.ColumnB = Row2.ColumnB &&
  Row1.ColumnC = Row2.ColumnC
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, all of the "select duplicates from MYSQL" questions I have seen use only one column as a comparison.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

If you want to count duplicates among multiple columns, use `group by`:

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, count(*) as NumDuplicates
from table
group by ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
```

If you only want the values that are duplicated, then the count is bigger than 1.  You get this using the `having` clause:

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, count(*) as NumDuplicates
from table
group by ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
having NumDuplicates > 1
```

If you actually want all the duplicate rows returns, then join the last query back to the original data:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, count(*) as NumDuplicates
      from table
      group by ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
      having NumDuplicates > 1
     ) tsum
     on t.ColumnA = tsum.ColumnA and t.ColumnB = tsum.ColumnB and t.ColumnC = tsum.ColumnC
```

This will work, assuming none of the column values are NULL.  If so, then try:

```
     on (t.ColumnA = tsum.ColumnA or t.ColumnA is null and tsum.ColumnA is null) and
        (t.ColumnB = tsum.ColumnB or t.ColumnB is null and tsum.ColumnB is null) and
        (t.ColumnC = tsum.ColumnC or t.ColumnC is null and tsum.ColumnC is null)
```

EDIT:

If you have `NULL` values, you can also use the `NULL`-safe operator:

```
     on t.ColumnA <=> tsum.ColumnA and
        t.ColumnB <=> tsum.ColumnB and
        t.ColumnC <=> tsum.ColumnC
```

Comment: Excellant answer, as usual, but the last example could be rewritten using MySQL's "null-safe" equals operator: `on t.ColumnA <=> tsum.ColumnA and t.ColumnB <=> tsum.ColumnB and t.ColumnC <=> tsum.ColumnC`

Comment: This answer seems to work, but the number of returns is a lot different than what I was expecting. Might have to code some java that uses for loops to double check it and give me some piece of mind. Thank you a lot for formatting your SQL code that way, with new lines and indenting, it really helped me understand what your code was actually doing!

Comment: Posterior = saved. Thanks -> you.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try using union or creating temporary table. but personally, i do recommend using union than that of creating temporary table cause it would take you a longer time doing that. try doing this:

```
  select field1, field2 from(
   select '' as field2, field1, count(field1) as cnt FROM list GROUP BY field2 HAVING cnt > 1
    union
    select ''as field1, field2, cound(field2) as cnt from list group by field1 having cnt > 1
  )
```

hope this make sense.:)