# Find duplicate value accross multiple column within same row in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please help find duplicate entries in multiple columns of same row in MySQL:

[image: table description]

Comment: Poor table design. Why several columns with same type of data?

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. Fix your schema design

Comment: It is not necessarily a poor table design. I can think of several good table design where this can happen and there can be the need to find out exactly what OP asks. Its just that the question as it is now is now at all complete with code, his attempts and an explanation why his solution doesn't work

Comment: Right @Cashbee !

Comment: Not good design, but sometimes one cannot fix that. What defines the set of columns to be checked for duplicates?

Comment: do you want to find entries that have duplicate columns, or do you want to find out which columns have the same value as another column?

Comment: Apart from clearifying your requirements as already stated above, you can split the table into  three with id and sample data, UNIONize them into one, select those which have duplicate id's  and this you can use to bring beack the record.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the records that have duplicates in columns you can use this query:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM tbl T1
JOIN  
    (SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id, sample1 AS n from tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, sample2 AS n from tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, sample3 AS n from tbl
    ) AS X
    GROUP BY id, n
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T2
    ON T1.id = T2.id;
```

You can also test it [**Here**](http://rextester.com/AGGLX99353)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure with `MySql`,

But in `PHP` below example will use.

**Example**

```
$query = "select * from table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['sample1'] == $row['sample2']) {
        // This row duplicate
    }
    else {
        // This row not duplicate
    }
}
```

Comment: but what if i have 100 columns in one row? It will too much write then!

Comment: So write this first in your question.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT Sample1, COUNT(*) C FROM tablename GROUP BY Sample1 HAVING C > 1;
```

[Finding duplicate values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/finding-duplicate-values-in-mysql)

[MySQL select records for duplicates using multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324328/mysql-select-records-for-duplicates-using-multiple-columns)

Comment: what if sample1 = 'Sam', sample2 = 'Rob', sample3 = 'Rob'?

Comment: Then add sample1, sample2 and sample3