# "Alter ignore" + "unique key" to remove duplicates, mysql and sql server

Tags: mysql, duplicates, key, unique, alter-table

I have a table containing some duplicate values for 1 column, ie with table `emails`

```
id email
1  test@test.com
2  test@test.com
3  more@most.many 
4  cook@sheep.com
```

I'd like to remove row with id '2'. And I'd like to do this by creating a unique index of `email` thus forcing the table to drop redundancies.

I have seen this method referenced here(http://www.it-iss.com/mysql/sql-removing-duplicate-records/) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000050/how-to-delete-first-of-a-double-record-with-alter-ignore-command-in-mysql

But when I attempt the statement 
`alter ignore table emails_test add unique index(email)`

I get a duplicate entry error for test@test.com, as if I never included the `ignore` keyword

Is there something I'm missing here? If this is not possible, what are alternative methods of deleting duplicates that are simpler than, say, using temporary tables [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: Interesting.  I see the same behavior you're describing when I'm using mysql 5.5.13, but it works as it should under mysql 5.5.29.  Maybe that's a bug that got fixed.  If it's possible, try upgrading your server.

Comment: Turns out, this is due to an InnoDB bug. Try "set session old_alter_table=1;" See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8053812/91165

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try doing this as a few separate steps:

```
CREATE TABLE _emails LIKE emails
ALTER TABLE _emails ADD UNIQUE INDEX(email)
INSERT IGNORE INTO _emails SELECT * FROM emails
RENAME TABLE emails TO emails_old, _emails TO emails
```