# MySQL inserting same rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, unique-index

There is a sql table like that
[image]

Indexes like that
[image]

```
INSERT INTO users_words(iduser,idword,status_of_word) VALUES(4,6,2);
INSERT INTO users_words(iduser,idword,status_of_word) VALUES(4,6,1);
INSERT INTO users_words(iduser,idword,status_of_word) VALUES(4,6,0);
INSERT INTO users_words(iduser,idword,status_of_word) VALUES(5,6,0);
INSERT INTO users_words(iduser,idword,status_of_word) VALUES(8,7,1);
INSERT INTO users_words(iduser,idword,status_of_word) VALUES(8,9,2);
```

> I want to a unique index is together with iduser,idword.
>   How to avoid inserting query with same values together index columns? 
>   For example: Bloking row inserting like 13 and 14 ( idusers_words ) rows

```
SELECT * FROM users_words;

> idusers_words  |  iduser | idword | status_of_word |
         12             4       6            2
         13             4       6            1
         14             4       6            0
         15             5       6            0
         16             8       7            1
         17             8       9            2
```

EDIT:

> I tried this code. But comes that error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'my_unique'"

```
ALTER TABLE users_words
ADD CONSTRAINT my_unique UNIQUE(iduser,idword);
```

Comment: At edit's error: That's because you already have some duplicate data in table. You have to remove it before adding constraint. Also, drop the earlier unique index/constraint, it's redundant.

Comment: @I_am_Batman thank you so much. you saved my life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unique index should only be on **iduser** and **idword** columns for your requirement.

You have index on `idusers_words,iduser and idword.` This means combination of all the three columns should be unique.

Since idusers_words is autoincrement, this  criteria would always be met,even though idusers and idword are duplicates, and records will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a constraint on a set of fields like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
)
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: ALTER TABLE users_words
 ADD CONSTRAINT my_unique UNIQUE(iduser,idword); 
i tried this code then
comes error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'my_unique'"

Comment: In databases usually you are supposed to prepare the data before you can add the constraint. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053447/mysql-alter-ignore-table-gives-integrity-constraint-violation