# Remove repeating 2nd entry of a column in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Somehow in my database many repeating rows have been created. I found the bug and fixed it.. But the problem is all the previously created rows are still there and i want to remove the 2nd repeating rows. Manual deleting is not possible as there are 40000+ row

Ex:

```
1 255 value1
2 255 value1
3 256 value2
4 257 value3
```

I need the result as

```
1 255 value1
3 256 value2
4 257 value3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867530/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-mysql-db
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE foobar ADD UNIQUE (title, SID)
```